# Is there any difference in how or when the connection closes between the following 2 methods?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, using

Below are 2 methods that are almost identical. I would like to know if there's any difference in how or when the context object will be disposed?

```
public List<Template> MethodVu()
{
  List<Template> templates;

  using (var context = new Entities())
  {
    templates = context.Templates.ToList();
  }

  return templates;
}

public List<Template> MethodDo()
{
  using (var context = new Entities())
  {
    return context.Templates.ToList();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No difference. In both cases, `context.Dispose()` will be called immediately when leaving the `using` block. The fact that you store the result in a variable and then return it or just return it makes no difference (irrelevant to the dispose, but in this specific example I'm guessing the compiler will optimize that away anyway).

What makes you ask the question?

---

More details: `using` is equivalent to a `try...finally` in the following sense.

The code:

```
using (var context = new Entities())
  {
    return context.Templates.ToList();
  }
```

...is exactly equivalent to:

```
{
   var context = new Entities();
   try {
      return context.Templates.ToList();
   }
   finally {
      if (context != null) { context.Dispose(); }
   }
}
```

See [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more.

Comment: thanks just wanted to make sure the object.Dispose() is called immediately in the shorter method.

Comment: I added a bit more explanation to make it clearer why there is no difference.